# Google signin change language

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, google-signin, google-identity

I've integrated a basic sign in like mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

Now I want to change the language of the button ("Sign in") *without using a custom button with own image*.

I've tried already this but it is not working:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer> {lang: 'de'} </script>
```

[like for other buttons using platform.js]

Thanks for any tips or maybe feedback from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the language character code the following way:
https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?hl=de